# how to make Global class?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class **Node**,then I created my tree node in my main
like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Node IProot = new Node("ANY-IP");           
}
```

I want to have access to this Node all the times even when I will go through another function(setting IProot global) for example I want to have

```
public static alarm generalize(alarm one,alarm two)
{       
   //some code
}
```

instead of

```
public static alarm generalize(alarm one,alarm two,Node IProot)
{       
  //some code
}
```

if this is totally wrong what should I do?

Because I don't have access to IProot, I have to get it as an input to my function so that I can code with IProot,but it is much better for me to not get it as an input.
I tried `static Node` where I defined IProot in the main, but that resulted in an error.  I also tried `static class Node` for my class, again no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
static Node IProot;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IProot = new Node("ANY-IP");
}
```

This instantiates the `IProot` object in your application's `Main` method, and will allow that instance of the object to be accessible in the methods in your class.

Answer (score 0):

If `generalize` is a method which can be applied to any `Node` object, it probably should be defined in the `Node` class instead of as a static method, as this is a more object-oriented approach. Then you could call it like this:

```
IProot.generalize(one, two);
```